# I need for Cypress screenshot to wait until after the second click() is complete

Tags: cypress

I am running the following test in Cypress:

```
context('Overview', () => {
  it('4.1 - From Patient Summaries Screen, click a patient name. - Should take user to the weekly Patient Overview screen.', () => {
 cy.login()

 cy.get('body div ul li a span')
   .should('exist')
   .should('be.visible')
   .contains('Patients')
   .click()

cy.get('td[data-cy=Name]')
  .should('be.visible')
  .contains('I.B. Sickly')
  .click()

cy.get('div[data-cy=headerTitle]')
  .should('be.visible')
  .screenshot() 
})
})
```

So the screenshot is being taken too soon. It is taken after the first get. However, the last block does not work because it will take a screenshot of the headerTitle literally. If I chain on `.screenshot()` to the second get block that will not work because then it will take a screenshot of just that patient name inside of `contains()`.

So most important of all I need for it to take a screenshot after the second click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of good answers that work, but I found out all I need to do is as follows:

```
context('Overview', () => {
  it('4.1 - From Patient Summaries Screen, click a patient name. - Should take user to the weekly Patient Overview screen.', () => {
 cy.login()

 cy.get('body div ul li a span')
   .should('exist')
   .should('be.visible')
   .contains('Patients')
   .click()

cy.get('td[data-cy=Name]')
  .should('be.visible')
  .contains('I.B. Sickly')
  .click()

cy.get('div[data-cy=patient-name]')
  .should('be.visible') 

cy.get('main div line')
  .should('be.visible')

cy.screenshot()
})
})
```

So what I did there was add another `get()` block that shows that the new screen has something unique to it and that it is visible and when it is, take the screenshot. That `should('be.visible')` seems to signal to Cypress that it's time to take the screenshot.

Comment: I made the same experience. The best way to test for something after you did any action is to pick up some element that was not present in the DOM-Tree before you did the action and then you can do any further tests.

Comment: By the way, you can accept your own answer so it is no longer marked as unanswered.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to what @agoff already mentioned about using `cy.screenshot()`. You can do two more additional things.

1. Makes sure the last element of the webpage is visible may be a footer or anything else, which will indicate that the page has loaded completely.
2. With Screenshot you can pass an optional parameters like `capture`.

```js
cy.get('lastElementSelector', {timeout: 6000}).should('be.visible')
cy.screenshot({capture:'fullPage'})
```

`capture` tells which parts of the Test Runner to capture. This value is ignored for element screenshot captures. Valid values are `viewport`, `fullPage`, or `runner`. When **viewport**, the application under test is captured in the current viewport. When **fullPage**, the application under test is captured in its entirety from top to bottom. When **runner**, the entire browser viewport, including the Cypress Command Log, is captured. For screenshots automatically taken on test failure, capture is always coerced to runner.

You can view all other optional parameters here - https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/screenshot#Arguments

Comment: the capture property is helpful, but its still taking the screenshot before it goes to the page it needs to go to upon `click()`. I need for it to take a screenshot after the second `click()` is complete.

Answer (score 0):

If you chain `.screenshot()` off of an element, it will [only screenshot that element.](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/screenshot#Screenshot-an-element)

You do not need to chain `.screenshot()` off of anything if you want to take a screenshot of the entire window. Simply call `cy.screenshot()`. `cy.screenshot()` defaults to capturing the entire page.

Comment: correct, unfortunately, it captures the entire window in between both gets, I need it to take the screenshot after the last get is run.

Comment: I don't think I follow. Do you want the entire window, or a specific element? Are you sure that the second screenshot is incorrect?